# How can I find out why my page crashes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash

I have written a page containing a lot of javascript and dynamic content.

Sometimes, like once every other day or so, it just crashes.

I get the "Aw, snap!" message
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en

Since it happens a lot on the same page I assume that it's because of code I've written. 
But I don't know how to troubleshoot it since I get to real error message.

I'm sorry I can't provide more info.
Does anyone know what may be causing this??

Comment: This mostly happens because the page has reached its memory limit, which is by default 200MB per page (Facebook for instance uses 130MB on average).

Answer (score 0):

To the right of the address bar in Chrome you will find three short lines one above another. This is the Customise and Control Button. Use this to open the Customise and Control Menu. From this menu choose Tools. From the Tools sub-menu Developer tools and Javascript Console should help you track possible errors.